# Как запустить action в template nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

Всем добра много денег и счастья. Подскажите пожалуйста не опытному.

В общем вопрос такой как запустить на выполнение действие при монтировании компонента, и можно ли передать в действие нагрузку(переменную)?

```js
export const state = () => ({
  Country: {
    item: {},
    items: []
  },
  City: {
    item: {},
    items: []
  },
  Basic: {}
});

export const mutations = {
  Country(currentState, payload) {
    currentState.Country = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload));
  },
  City(currentState, payload) {
    currentState.City = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload));
  },
  Basic(currentState, payload) {
    currentState.Basic = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload));
  }
};

export const actions = {
  Country({ commit }, payload) {
    commit("Country", payload);
  },
  City({ commit }, payload) {
    commit("City", payload);
  },
  async Basic({ commit }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await this.$axios.get(url).then(response => {
        return response;
      });
      console.log(data);
      await commit("Basic", data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
};

export const getters = {
  getCountry: currentState => currentState.Country,
  getCity: currentState => currentState.City,
  getBasic: currentState => currentState.Basic
};
```

Как запустить здесь

```
async Basic({ commit }) {
try {
  const { data } = await this.$axios.get(url).then(response => {
    return response;
  });
  console.log(data);
  await commit("Basic", data);
  } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  throw error;
   }
 }
```

```js
export default {
  name: "SettingsBasic",
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("settings", ["getCountry","getCity","getBasic"]),
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.getBasic()
  },
  methods: {

  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполнить `action` в компоненте при монтировании можно так:

```
export default {
  name: "SettingsBasic",
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("settings", ["getCountry","getCity","getBasic"]),
  },
  async mounted() {
    const payload = {}
    await this.$store.dispatch('getBasic', payload) // namespace указываем через `/`, например `settings/getBasic`
  }
}
```